# Solder heat dissipation

Tags: soldering

We have been soldering LED boards together for years with no issues. Recently engineering has gone to a new board design and we got the first samples in this week. Because of the improved design and better heat dissipation of the board my team is have great difficulty soldering lead wires and connecting boards in series with wire to the solder pads on the LED boards.

The solder will not stay molten long enough to insert a wire even with the soldering tip still in direct contact with the solder pad. I have tried different temperatures and methods but all have resulted in failed solder joints.

Looking for any advice on methods/ materials to try out.

We are currently using Kester lead free 275 .062 wire at 625 degrees Fahrenheit

Comment: Better soldering irons and more heating time. Also 625°C is way too hot.

Comment: @PlasmaHH 625°F = 330°C, not too hot.

Comment: Photo of the board might help. Is it FR4 or some kind of special substrate such as aluminum?

Comment: @ratchetfreak: 625°F = 1157°F way too hot.

Comment: Hang on, you're pushing a cold wire into molten solder? Normally you bring the parts together, then heat, then apply solder.

Comment: *at 625 degrees* Let's hope that you mean that in degrees Franenheis or whatever obscure unit you Americans use. Then write 625 degrees F or whatever. We're engineers here, we expect **standard units**. And for temperature that is in degrees Celcius or Kelvin (but **not** degrees Kelvin !)

Comment: @Finbarr or at the least tin the wire first, then insert, then reheat wire and hole/attachment together, then solder.

Comment: You may need to pre-heat the entire board too if it's a high thermal dissipation board... eg. aluminum substrate

Comment: Using a Hakko FX-951 75 W (400-840°F) soldering station.

Comment: Our current process is to lay a solder bead on each of the pads and then to lay the wire on top of the bead, press the solder tip onto the wire to press it into the solder bead.

Comment: wire is pre-tinned, I will try to post a couple of pics after my morning meeting. Thanks for the input guys. This is my first post on this site so bear with me if you can.

Comment: I'd also add. your PCB guys need to look at the thermal isolation for those landing pads...

Comment: Boards: 2oz metal core board, Copper-clad 0.062in aluminum core (Berquist P/N MP-06503). The soldermask is white Taiyo P/N PSR-4000 LEW1

Comment: Worst case you may need one of these..https://www.sra-solder.com/soldering-equipment/pre-heating-stations

Comment: Our board configuration is laid out on heat sinks in a lighting fixture before soldering takes place. A pre-heating station would not be practical unfortunately.

Comment: Then you might have to stop doing that. The very purpose of heat sinks is incompatible with the process of soldering. If soldering the boards before you attach heat sinks is impossible, have you considered spot welding instead?

Comment: Or switch to a crimped connector.

Comment: We have used crimped connectors on past versions of our LED boards and they have their own issues that we are getting away from. We have been soldering on our current boards for close to 4 years in the same configurations, same heat sinks same materials, etc and have not encountered any issues. Our Electrical Engineer is working with the manufacturer, i am just trying to bring something to the table from the Operations side. I have to do some more testing this afternoon and I was hoping  for some advice. I thank everyone again for their input.

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way to get the PCB soldered by hand is to heat it up to 50-80°C so that your soldering iron has less heat to provide. The best way, in my experience, to do this is to use a heat plate. There are special heat plates sold for soldering, but basically any that you can reasonably well control would work. Word of advice: because the PCBs you get are not humidity controlled anymore, do not heat the PCB up too much (i.e. going over 100°C) without first drying the PCB at around 50°C for a while. Otherwise your components will go *pop*.

Answer (score 2):

The best kind of soldering iron for aluminum core boards is probably Metcal's RF system, which uses a ~13MHz RF drive to send power to the tip. The temperature regulation takes place via the Curie point of a material in the tip similar to the old WTCP Magnastat from Weller, but better.

It appears that Metcal's patent has expired and you can buy similar and allegedly "compatible" systems from Hakko. Around USD $600 for a solder station. The tips have a fixed setpoint temperature associated with them.

You should ask for a demo before buying, or get a return authorization if it doesn't work for you. You could also consider the higher power conventional stations such as FX-951 and FM203-01. The latter is 140W which ought to be plenty.

Answer (score 1):

75W seems fine (I use 90W but that's not a lot more).

Since no-one mentioned it: use a big thick tip on your soldering iron, as heat transfer is dependent on the cross-section of the tip. A chisel or "screwdriver-style" tip provides a large flat contact area that you can press down for maximum heat transfer into the work piece. A thin round tip won't work as well. Put a small drop of solder on the tip.

Also set it to 400-420°C and work fast.

Comment: That's true. If the brute force approach of a bigger and hotter tip doesn't work, there's always the option of an even bigger and even hotter tip.

Comment: Yeah, basically if a hammer doesn't solve the problem, use a bigger hammer ;)

Comment: We currently use the chisel tip.

Comment: Hmm... If your metal core PCB is too thermally efficient, this one here would be interested in knowing about it: https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/329456/high-power-led-on-aluminium-core-pcb